# I am unable to access or write to etc/hosts file

Tags: permissions, filesystem, hosts

I am attempting to edit the`etc/hosts` file. I am able to access it through the graphic file system to find that it is read only. When using `sudo nano etc/hosts` as many suggest, I see that the directory `etc` doesn't exist although i can see it in the GUI, so I assume it is just creating a new file in a new directory rather than opening the existing one. I cannot even make `/etc/` my working directory as if it does not exist. Both `etc` and `hosts` file exist I am just unable to access it through the terminal or edit it through the graphic interface.

I run into a similar issue when using `chmod` or `chown`, being told the file/directory does not exist.

I find the file in question under "other locations" in the file manager and was able to drag the `/etc/` folder to my bookmarks thinking that would do something but it didnt. Is this a partition or mounting issue? I apologize if this is silly I am very new to ubuntu.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a slash in the beginning of the filename ... it should be
/etc/hosts ...
The difference is that without the slash,the path/filename is relative to the directory you currently are in. WITH the slash
it is absolute from the top of the filesystem.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes it was just the slash I was missing. Silly mistakes.